# GLKit Multi-sampling with OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, ios-simulator, opengl-es-3.0

I am in the process of migrating a small iPad application from OpenGL ES 2.0 to OpenGL ES 3.0. In the App, I use a subclass of `GLKView` to handle all my drawing, though the only GLKit features I use are:

```
self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3]; // Or 2
self.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormatNone;
self.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
self.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
self.drawableStencilFormat = GLKViewDrawableStencilFormatNone;
self.enableSetNeedsDisplay = YES;
// ... gl code following
```

My `-drawRect` method looks like this:

```
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

[_currentProgram use]; // Use program
glUniformMatrix4fv([_currentProgram getUniformLocation:@"modelViewProjectionMatrix"], 1, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);

// ...
if (isES3) {
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
}
else {
   glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);
}
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, verticiesLength);
```

---

I do not yet have a OpenGL ES 3.0-capable device so all of my OpenGL ES 3.0 testing is being done in the iOS Simulator. OpenGL ES 2.0 testing is done on-device and in-simulator.

As expected, in `ES2`, the screen is cleared to white immediately on startup (`-drawRect` having been called once and no vertices to draw yet). However, when I make the swap to `ES3`, the context is successfully created, no `gl` calls fail, and yet the screen does not clear as it should - it just appears as a black screen. Fishing around for what was going wrong, I decided to remove multi-sampling:

```
self.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisampleNone;
```

And it worked! (Albeit without antialiasing.) My question is therefore, are there any known issues with `GLKit` multi-sampling with OpenGL ES 3.0 in the iOS Simulator (iPad, iPad Retina and iPad Retina (64-Bit))? My laptop has more than enough free memory to cope with the multi-sampling.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running in the emulator? I am observing the same behavior (black screen when multisampling is enabled) on real iPad mini retina hardware with iOS 7.0.4. I am wondering if this is a bug that was fixed in later revisions of iOS.

Comment: I'm glad someone else has picked up this problem! I believe it was 7.1(.0). I've since updated Xcode and haven't reverified that the problem still exists for 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a very asynchronous API. For example, if you call `glClear`, you should not expect the screen to be cleared when the call returns. You can only reliably look at the result of the rendering you produced after you finished rendering the frame, and it is displayed (typically by swapping the buffers when using double buffered rendering).

So what you're observing most likely does not mean anything. Does everything look fine at the end of the frame? If yes, there's no reason to be worried.

The difference is likely caused in the different rendering process if multisampling is enabled. In this case, rendering goes to a higher resolution buffer first, and is only downsampled to the actual framebuffer at the end of the frame.

Comment: I think the question changed once or twice since I wrote this answer. Not sure if it's still on target. It initially sounded like the poster was looking at the rendering immediately after the clear call, but it sounds different now.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy, chose the device type to be iPad, not universal, from the General>Deployment Info menu, that will fix it.